# List Instagram posts by the hashtag

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to pull instagram posts by the hashtag, it can be by Wordpress plugin or in pure PHP, libraries that still work and do that. I tried in many ways and was unsuccessful ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the code from base to do some works with Instagram, you can use Instagram API's to coding everything that u want!

take a look at https://www.instagram.com/developer/.

You should be starting from Facebook.com https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram

or

try an independent solution here https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader to achieve it.

Hopefully, this will help you out!